$A.get('$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Name') is undefined
I am using a script in the head markup file in the experience cloud.
$A.get('$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Email') works fine,
but $A.get('$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Name') returns null.
I tried debugging it, and it looks like $A.get('$SObjectType.CurrentUser') returns only id and email fields. Are we able to modify it to include name as well?
Since I have the email, can I add some code with it to fetch name?
